# Finding the Geometry within which a Point falls

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-database

I have the following query, which takes on average about 4 seconds. How might one improve the query such that the same response comes back faster?

```
SELECT * FROM geometries g 
    ORDER BY 
      ST_Distance(g.wkb_geometry, 
         ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-77.8252923, 39.4328016), ST_SRID(g.wkb_geometry))) 
    LIMIT 1
```

(I understand that this actually finds the *nearest* geometry to a point, which is the same as the geometry in which the point falls unless the point doesn't fall in any geometry. I'm open to seeing other approaches as well.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong function. Use ST_Intersects instead.

```
SELECT *
FROM geometries g
WHERE ST_Intersects(g.wkb_geometry, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-77.8252923, 39.4328016), 4326));
```

**Update 1:**
Remember to add a spatial index:

```
CREATE INDEX geometries_geo_idx ON geometries USING GIST ( wkb_geometry );
```

and of course, update the statistics of the tables

```
VACUUM ANALYZE
```

Comment: The query is still nearly 4 seconds long...what can I do to improve that?

Comment: most likely, you do not have a spatial index on the geometry. Updating answer

Comment: We actually *do* have a spatial index on `wkb_geometry`. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @ChrisCashwell Did you switch to the ST_Intersects query?  Your original query cannot take advantage of the GIST index.

Comment: @ChrisCashwell Just want to make sure I am getting this right. Are you telling me that you switched the query, created the index, vacuum analyzed it, and that the result of that is a similar runtime?

Comment: @ChrisCashwell curious as to why it was not working before

Comment: @RagiYaserBurhum it just needed a vacuum analyze.